# SolrJ and LocalDate and LocalDateTime

Tags: solr, solrj

SolrJ serializes the LocalDate and LocalDateTime but they are not search-able as dates (or date ranges) but rather as strings. If one wants to have it search-able, one has to convert it to java.util.Date before persisting with SolrJ.

Is there a way to define a custom serializer for SolrJ or to have LocalDate and LocalDateTime also marked as date field (and therefore search-able)?

Thank you!

EDIT: Code samples

```
String zkHosts = "localhost:2181";
CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHosts).build();
client.setDefaultCollection("playground");

Person test = Person.builder().id("UID-333").createdTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now()).dateOfBirth(LocalDate.now()).gender("male").build();
client.addBean("person", test, 1000);

client.close();
```

This is what is saved in Solr:

```
{
  "id":"UID-333",
  "dateOfBirth":["java.time.LocalDate:2018-05-15"],
  "dateOfBirth_str":["java.time.LocalDate:2018-05-15"],
  "gender":["male"],
  "gender_str":["male"],
  "timestamp":["java.time.LocalDateTime:2018-05-15T15:00:12.433"],
  "timestamp_str":["java.time.LocalDateTime:2018-05-15T15:00:12.433"]
}
```

Of course, the corresponding properties of the entity are annotated with `@Field`.

Comment: could you show example of your SolrJ code?

Comment: Done, I edited my question to include some samples.